# Windows hosting environment for application instances?

Tags: hosting, production-environment

My team has developed a server application, each customer has its own instance of the server application that is hosted locally within our data center. The applications opens a number of TCP, UDP, SIP and RTP connections used by remote clients.

I have some questions regarding hosting of the server instances, in the current situation we make use of exe-files that are executed via a self-developed "Host Controller" using the System.Diagnostics.Process namespace to run the instances.

The reason for this is that individual instances of the application shall not affect other instances in the event of crashes, etc.

Is this a good choice of hosting? Is there any kind of infrastructure for hosting these applications similar to IIS, or can I also host these applications in IIS?

I am looking for a more stable hosting solution for those server applications, I've been looking for previous threads on the subject but does not find any good answers. The company wants to host the applications locally so a cloud-based solution is not the right answer here.

All answers are gratefully received, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question, I believe that you already have a hosting server in your data center. What you're asking is ... your development method like creating a separate instances for each remote connection is suitable or not? Am I right? Or you need help to find out a correct type of hosting (VPS, Reseller, Cloud or Dedicated) for this ?

I believe that separating instances from each other is a very good idea ... but it will increase the load on the server.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear in my description of the problem. What I am wondering is if there is a good idea to host all instances via the internally developed "Host Conroller" with System.Diagnostics.Process to run instances. Or if it is simply a better option to use IIS and WAS, with built-in hosting capabilities in all its meaning. Maybe implementing the instances as windows services would be a good idea?